# Baseline shift and letter aligned verticaly on selectable text?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I'm not sure where to look since it seems its super specific and I don't know enough about CSS to know how to do it myself.

I want to reproduce the text formatting on the picture below in HTML and CSS so the text can be selected and copied/pasted as its supposed to be read.

I don't know how to have the letters be aligned centrally in regard to the other letter in the pair (directly below it), and to make the baseline shift but still have the text be in one paragraph or header.

Thanks for your help!
[image: What I try to make]

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you're trying to achieve. It's still one word when you select, and copy/paste.

Basically to wrap up each letter into a `<i>` or so, and set `position:relative; top:15px;` or similar value to shift some of them.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aL9ha7u0/)

```css
.e {
    background: silver;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}
.e i {
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: crimson;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline;
}
.e i:nth-child(4), .e i:nth-child(6), .e i:nth-child(8) {
    text-transform: none;
}
.e i:nth-child(2), .e i:nth-child(4), .e i:nth-child(7), .e i:nth-child(9) {
    top: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.e i:nth-child(4) {
    color: yellow;
}
.e i:nth-child(5):after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre; 
}
```

```html
<div class="e"><i>e</i><i>x</i><i>h</i><i>i</i><i>b</i><i>i</i><i>t</i><i>i</i><i>o</i><i>n</i></div>
```